# Drag drop uploader with html page

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I want to create control, which uploads file to the server using JavaScript, with the following features

1. Drag drop support
2. Use only HTML and JavaScript(without any server side code)

Comment: No server side languages? Where do you want to upload the files then?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be possible without any server side scripting to process the upload and save it on the server: http://robertnyman.com/2010/12/16/utilizing-the-html5-file-api-to-choose-upload-preview-and-see-progress-for-multiple-files

Comment: `yes you are right without server side how it come possible` I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean impossible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with node.js which is basically  javascript , you can try using it  along wiuth html5 elements instead of php or other server side languages to upload it to the server. But there is no way around a server side if you are going to uploade a file since it has to be stored somewhere.